# Почему происходит ошибка Object is not iterable?

Tags: python, django

Вывожу данные из бд в таблицу html. Происходит ошибка 'State' object is not iterable
**models.py**

```
class School_class(models.Model):
school_class = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text = 'Класс')
def __str__(self):
    return self.school_class

class People(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text = 'Имя учащегося')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text = 'Фамилия учащегося')
school_class = models.ForeignKey(School_class, help_text = 'Класс ученика', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class State(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(help_text = 'Дата')
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = (
    ('+', '+'),
    ('-', '-')
    ))
people = models.ForeignKey(People, help_text = 'Фамилия, имя учащегося', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.date, self.people.__str__())

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('date-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date', 'people']
```

**views.py**

```
class StateListView(generic.ListView):
model = State
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
path('state/', views.StateListView.as_view(), name = 'state'),
```

]

**И, наконец, state_list:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'state' %}">Date</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Nothing!</a></li>
      </ul>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">
      {% block content %}<h1>State List</h1>

  {% if object_list %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        People/day
      </td>
      {% for list in object_list%}
        <td>{{ list.date}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for i in object_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ i.people }}
        </td>
        {% for d in i %}
          <td>
            {% if d.status %}{{ d.status }}{% else %}?{% endif %}
          </td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% else %}
    <p>Данных нет!</p>
  {% endif %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот примерно как должна выглядеть таблица на сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему происходит ошибка и как починить? django:2.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас лишний цикл:

```
  {% for d in i %}
      <td>
        {% if d.status %}{{ d.status }}{% else %}?{% endif %}
      </td>
  {% endfor %}
```

В вашем случае `i` это объект класса `State` и он не итерируемый.